# Incompatible pointer type file txt for loop

Tags: c, pointers, strtok, strcpy

I am getting an error for the below code. I was wondering if I am missing memory allocation or what could be the pointer issue. Any help would be wonderful , thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_ITEM_NAME_STRING    25
#define MAX_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_STRING     80

typedef struct 
{
    char name[MAX_ITEM_NAME_STRING]; //25 value
    char description[MAX_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_STRING]; //80 value
}Item;

int ItemReadItems(Item *items[], int maxItems, char *filename){
    FILE * itemFile = fopen(filename, "r");
    // file is 6 lines "comb","a small comb"[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    char ch;// loads a list of items from a txt file with comma delimited fields
    char line[MAX_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_STRING + MAX_ITEM_NAME_STRING + 10];
    int i =0;
    if(itemFile == NULL)
    { return -1;}// if not able reutrn -1 unable to open
    for(i<maxItems; i++)
    {// fills item array items with contents of a file from items.txt
        
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), itemFile) != NULL){
          strcpy(items[i]->name, strtok(line, ","));
          strcpy(items[i]->description, strtok(line, ","));
        }
    }
    fclose(itemFile);
    return i;// return a # of objects loaded from filename   
}
```

Error:

```
/mnt/c/Users/liloc/Documents/CSCV352/Exercise 6 Files/Exercise6_1/Item.c: In function ‘ItemReadItems’:
/mnt/c/Users/liloc/Documents/CSCV352/Exercise 6 Files/Exercise6_1/Item.c:15:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   15 |         fgets(line, sizeof(line), itemFile);
      |               ^~~~
      |               |
      |               char **
In file included from /mnt/c/Users/liloc/Documents/CSCV352/Exercise 6 Files/Exercise6_1/Item.h:3,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/liloc/Documents/CSCV352/Exercise 6 Files/Exercise6_1/Item.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:564:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
  564 | extern char *fgets (char *__restrict __s, int __n, FILE *__restrict __stream)
      |              ^~~~~
/mnt/c/Users/liloc/Documents/CSCV352/Exercise 6 Files/Exercise6_1/Item.c:16:39: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strtok’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   16 |         strcpy(items[i]->name, strtok(line, ","));
      |                                       ^~~~
      |                                       |
      |                                       char **
In file included from /mnt/c/Users/liloc/Documents/CSCV352/Exercise 6 Files/Exercise6_1/Item.h:4,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/liloc/Documents/CSCV352/Exercise 6 Files/Exercise6_1/Item.c:1:
/usr/include/string.h:336:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
  336 | extern char *strtok (char *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __delim)
      |              ^~~~~~
/mnt/c/Users/liloc/Documents/CSCV352/Exercise 6 Files/Exercise6_1/Item.c:17:46: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strtok’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   17 |         strcpy(items[i]->description, strtok(line, ","));
      |                                              ^~~~
      |                                              |
      |                                              char **
In file included from /mnt/c/Users/liloc/Documents/CSCV352/Exercise 6 Files/Exercise6_1/Item.h:4,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/liloc/Documents/CSCV352/Exercise 6 Files/Exercise6_1/Item.c:1:
/usr/include/string.h:336:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
  336 | extern char *strtok (char *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __delim)
      |              ^~~~~~
```

Comment: `line` is an array of `char*`, not `char`. Fix that first. Then fix the broken `feof` logic in your loop.

Comment: Remove link to error message and paste the error as text.

Comment: You want to check the return code of `fgets()` instead of `if(eof(...))`

Comment: @AllanWind IE like the following? ```While(fgets(line, sizeof(line), itemFile) !=EOF)``` and remove the if feof

Comment: Why: `int i = 0; if (itemFile == NULL) { return -1; } for (i; i < maxItems; i++)` instead of `if (itemFile == NULL) { return -1; } for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; i++)` ?? It makes you code hard to read for no reason.

Comment: Almost fgets() returns NULL on error.

Comment: The error you show does not appear for the code you've put in the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the int i being defined in the for loop was causing a return error not seeing the i

Comment: I see, but then remove it from `for(i;` - it's not needed.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried removing the 10 and I am still getting the errors for ```strcpy``` and ```fgets```

Comment: @Nikki Look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YTaEqYxjn) - it's the code you have in the question. It compiles fine.

Comment: @Nikki The answer below addresses your initial question.  Why don't you work a little on your program, and if you still need help open another question (new code with match new error message)?

Comment: @AllanWind thank you very much for the help!! I will, at least now it complies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @WhozCaig said change:

```
char *line[MAX_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_STRING + MAX_ITEM_NAME_STRING + 10];
```

to:

```
char line[MAX_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_STRING + MAX_ITEM_NAME_STRING + 10];
```

What is the 10?  Define another constant for that.

`ch` is not used.  Remove it.

`fgets()` returns NULL on error or EOF.  Use that instead of `if(feof() {...}`.  You don't want to execute those `strcpy()` when `fgets()` fails.

Comment: OP made the `line` change some time ago so now the error does not match the code anymore.

Comment: So op should close issue and open another right?  I mean, this was the initial answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. It seem like OP just changed the code in the question without actually testing it.

Comment: What is an OP? is that the win-linux WSL?

Comment: @Nikki: OP stands for "original poster", i.e. the person who made the original post. That term is being used to refer to you.